# Ember event route, and defining individual event function

Tags: ember.js, model, routes, handlebars.js

I am new to Ember but not Javascript so sorry for the ignorance in advance guys!! I have a routing question if anyone can help me. I have generated an events table with the route as events, but I am trying to configure the route and ALL necessary attributes associated with it to display a single event onClick to dim the background of the table and have specific content of the one event pop up. Been racking my brain to figure this out but only been using ember for about a month or less. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please give a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It seems that what you are looking for is [dynamic segments](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments), I would recommend going over the guide a few times before getting started with ember, there is also a [slack channel](https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com/) feel free to join up and ask questions there ^^

Comment: Ok thanks again. I looked into this already and it appears I have the router and the routes properly configured as dynamic segments. I think the issue is that I feel I am still missing something. For example, is the onHover feature part of the component section which then allows the model to loop the necessary data? I have the handlebars, a route model and the router configured but for a dynamic feature like this I am a little unclear on what else needs to be included.

Comment: Please create a https://ember-twiddle.com/ with your current state, like @MartinZabel suggested.